# How to set XAudio2 dll version

Tags: c++, visual-c++, dll, visual-studio-2015, xaudio2

My MSVC 2015 C++ application project uses `xaudio2.lib`. So the .cvxproj contains a line

```
<AdditionalDependencies>xaudio2.lib;%(AdditionalDependencies)</AdditionalDependencies>
```

Looking into .exe built, I can find a line `XAudio2_8.dll`.

So it seems that the compiler (or the linker) has decided to use just 2_8 version.

It leads to a problem that my app cannot be run on Windows 7 machine, because only lower versions of `XAudio2.dll` are installed there, and it cannot find `XAudio2_8.dll`.

So how can I fix/modify my project so that the resulting .exe can be run on Windows 7? How can I specify to use `XAudio2_7.dll`, for instance?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> **UPDATE**: XAudio 2.9 functionality is now available for Windows 7 SP1, Windows 8, and Windows 10 via the [XAudio2Redist](https://aka.ms/Xaudio2Redist). Therefore, you *DO NOT NEED* the legacy DirectX SDK anymore to target Windows 7 with XAudio2 or if you want xWMA support on Windows 8.x. The code below has been updated for the scenario of when you include the [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.XAudio2.Redist/) package.

If you are using the Windows 8.0 SDK or Windows 8.1 SDK, then the `xaudio2.h` headers and `xaudio2.lib` all link to XAudio 2.8 which requires Windows 8 or later. If you had set `_WIN32_WINNT` correctly for a Windows 7 compatible exe (i.e. `/D _WIN32_WINNT=0x0601` or`/D _WIN32_WINNT=0x0600`) then when you built your application you would have seen a build-time failure precisely because XAudio 2.8 is not supported for Windows Vista or Windows 7

If you use the Windows 10 SDK, then the `xaudio2.h` header uses XAudio 2.9 if `_WIN32_WINNT` is set to `0x0A00` which works when linked against `xaudio2.lib` on Windows 10 only. If using the Windows 10 SDK, you can set `WIN32_WINNT` to `0x0602` or `0x0603`, link against `xaudio2_8.lib` and it will again use XAudio 2.8.

To support Windows 7 SP1 or later, you should use the *XAudio2Redist* which provides XAudio 2.9 functionality on Windows 7 SP1, Windows 8, and Windows 8.1. On Windows 10 it automatically forwards to the OS version of XAudio 2.9--if you are only supporting Windows 10 you don't need the *XAudio2Redist* since XAudio 2.9 is part of the Windows 10 OS. The NuGet package includes `xaudio2_9redist.lib` and `xapobaseredist.lib`.

To support Windows 7 RTM or earlier, you have to use the [legacy DirectX SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/directx-sdk--august-2009) to get the XAudio 2.7 headers, and you must deploy `XAUDIO2_7.DLL` using the [legacy DirectSetup](https://walbourn.github.io/not-so-direct-setup/) package. Because of the header conflicts with the Windows 8.x SDK and Windows 10 SDK, it's actually best to do a full-path reference to the legacy Direct SDK headers in addition to needing to set up the project include paths correctly.

For example, *DirectX Tool Kit for Audio* [DX11](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK) / [DX12](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK12) has the following in the `Audio.h` header:

```
#if defined(USING_XAUDIO2_REDIST) || (_WIN32_WINNT >= 0x0A00 /*_WIN32_WINNT_WIN10*/)
#define USING_XAUDIO2_9
#elif (_WIN32_WINNT >= 0x0602 /*_WIN32_WINNT_WIN8*/)
#define USING_XAUDIO2_8
#else
#define USING_XAUDIO2_7_DIRECTX
#endif

#if defined(USING_XAUDIO2_8) || defined(USING_XAUDIO2_9)
#include <xaudio2.h>
#include <xaudio2fx.h>
#include <x3daudio.h>
#include <xapofx.h>

#ifndef USING_XAUDIO2_REDIST
#if defined(USING_XAUDIO2_8) && defined(NTDDI_WIN10)
#pragma comment(lib,"xaudio2_8.lib")
#else
#pragma comment(lib,"xaudio2.lib")
#endif
#endif
#else // USING_XAUDIO2_7_DIRECTX
// Using XAudio 2.7 requires the DirectX SDK
#include <C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Include\comdecl.h>
#include <C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Include\xaudio2.h>
#include <C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Include\xaudio2fx.h>
#include <C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Include\xapofx.h>
#pragma warning(push)
#pragma warning( disable : 4005 )
#include <C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Include\x3daudio.h>
#pragma warning(pop)
#pragma comment(lib,"x3daudio.lib")
#pragma comment(lib,"xapofx.lib")
#endif
```

See [Adding the DirectX Tool Kit for Audio](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/Adding-the-DirectX-Tool-Kit-for-Audio), [XAudio2 and Windows 8](https://aka.ms/F2xp1a), [Known Issues: XAudio 2.7](https://walbourn.github.io/known-issues-xaudio-2-7/), and [Using the Windows Headers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog/using-the-windows-headers).

Comment: Links need to be updated due to the blog content getting moved to github:
[XAudio2 and Windows 8](https://walbourn.github.io/xaudio2-and-windows-8/).
[Known Issues: XAudio 2.7](https://walbourn.github.io/known-issues-xaudio-2-7/).

Comment: Hi, this seems like a good place to make a comment.  It looks like Microsoft dropped the ball with the 3D stuff.  They included the x3daudio.h in the include directory for Win 10 but forgot the libraries.  Use C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Lib\ x64 or x86 for the missing X3DAudio.lib and XAPOFX.lib.  I made my own directory for those as the dll was already in the DX9 redistributable.

Comment: ``x3daudio.lib`` and ``xapofx.lib`` are not needed for XAudio 2.8 or later. Those entry-points are already in the ``xaudio2.lib``.

Comment: Technical aside: XAudio 2.7 used "COM initialization" so for this version ``XAudio2Create`` was an inline wrapper around ``CoCreateInstance`` so there was no ``xaudio2.lib``. With XAudio 2.8 or later, it doesn't use COM and instead the ``XAudio2Create`` entry is in ``xaudio2.lib``. Since there was already an import library, we just added the content from ``x3daudio.lib`` and ``xapofx.lib`` to the one library. In all versions of XAudio2, there's a distinct helper ``xapobase.lib`` library for writing custom xAPOs.

Comment: @ChuckWalbourn [microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/xaudio2/xaudio2-versions#xaudio-28-windows-8x) says that (at least for XAudio 2.8) we need to link `XAUDIO2_8.LIB` which now is a 1-package-all XAudio2, X3DAudio and XPOFX interface.

Comment: @Nikos - good catch. The code above had assumed you were using Windows 8 SDK to build for XAudio 2.8 for Windows 8--which was still true when I supported VS 2013. For the Windows 10 SDK, you have to use xaudio2_8.lib.